# Netsuite - weight/dims/package relationships

Tags: formula, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

My workplace just switched to NetSuite and it's some cool stuff. I've been creating workflows and ran into a snag after I had the thought that it would be cool if weight and dimension fields could auto populate based on the "package" type you can select from a dropdown.

Has anyone done something like this or know if it's possible? The basic logic would be "After field edit" - once a package type is selected from the dropdown, the product weight and dimensions that correspond to that package type are populated automatically in the separate fields (we need these separate fields to calculate dimensional weight in some instances, and for certain sales channels) It doesn't look like the weight/dims for packages have internal IDs, but the package itself does "shippackage" is the internal ID.

I've really only tried a couple of formulas at this point but can't seem to get it going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately workflows do not support access to 'sublist' fields - only 'body' fields, so if you are trying to modify the Packages sublist on an item fulfillment you cannot use a workflow to achieve this.

You could achieve this using a 'Field Changed' event on a client script.

Comment: cool thanks. I'm pretty new to javascript so I will have to dig in some more. Any chance you would have any ideas on how this would be started or a way to point me in the right direction? trying to find an example of a similar script.

Comment: There are some rather simplistic examples in NetSuite's help documentation.  See [SuiteScript 2.0 Client Script Type](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43794) for the SS2.0 version.  I'd recommend starting and sticking with SS2.0 if you're just starting, but there are also some for [SuiteScript 1.0](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10584) if you prefer.

Comment: As of 2018.1 NetSuite introduced limited support for some sublists, but it's currently only available for transaction lines and not packages.

Comment: @michoel Interesting!  I must have missed that development - thanks for weighing in!

Comment: HI Krypton, would you be able to maybe help me out with a skeleton for this script. There's a lot of our business logic that could benefit from this type of script but I'm having trouble finding a starting point